# Forward All Traffic to Socks5 Proxy

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian 10 with SSHUTTLE but it is rather slow at around 5 Mbps. With a standard SSH based socks5 proxy I've been able to get around 40-50 Mbps. I don't have much experience with iptables, so I will try to explain what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to use iptables to forward TCP traffic from `eth0` to a SSH based socks proxy. I have a `192.168.220.1/24` subnet on `eth0` interface. The internet connection to the Pi runs on the `usb0` interface. The Pi is a connected as a client the `192.168.42.223/24` subnet via `usb0`.

These are my current iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o usb0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i usb0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o usb0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: socks5 proxy will require client configuration, you'll have to set the HTTP_PROXY or whatever for each application for them to use it.   I don't understand this scenario in which ssh is so much faster than whatever else , but instead of thinking of this as a layer 7 problem, I'm tempted to think of it as a lower layer problem.  Route all your traffic through whatever host can talk to you and the world  faster than you can talk to the world .